# Unit Test c# for Private Method

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I need to test the `CheckWarehouseAvailability` private method in an abstract class.

```
public abstract class BaseAPI
{
    private void CheckWarehouseAvailability(Order order)
    {
        //codes here
    }
}

public class Processor : BaseAPI
{

}
```

Here is my TestMethod

```
Processor pro = new Processor();
PrivateObject privBase = new PrivateObject(pro, new PrivateType(typeof(BaseAPI)));
var retVal = privBase.Invoke("CheckWarehouseAvailability(order)");
Assert.AreEqual(true, retVal);
```

When I run the test method, I got this error: `An exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occured in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code`

Comment: The argument (`order`) needs to be constructed before the call and passed as an additional argument to `Invoke`. Like it is currently written, you attempt to invoke a method which has the string "(order)" as a part of its name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to instantiate the `Order` argument of `CheckWarehouseAvailability` and pass it as an argument to `PrivateObject.Invoke()`:

```
var order = new Order(); 
var retVal = privBase.Invoke("CheckWarehouseAvailability", order);
// ... Assert
```

> MSDN: [`PrivateObject.Invoke(String, Object[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243741.aspx)

Also, I'm not sure what you are asserting here:

```
Assert.AreEqual(true, retVal);
```

...as `CheckWarehouseAvailability` has it's return type set to `void`, not `bool`.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get the method via reflection

```
MethodInfo methodName = privBase.GetType().GetMethod("ShowGrid",
           BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

then invoke the method with your params

```
var retVal=methodName .Invoke(privBase, order);
```